# Update Lookup filter of Unlock package metadata

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, org-shape

Please hear me out before marking this question as a duplicate or downvote.

We are trying to migrate from Unpackage monolith to Unlock packages.
For this, We have decided to split into 3 packages.

1. Object-Base package (contains all the objects)
2. Core (contains all the common utilities, depends on Object-Base package)
3. Product Package. (divided by business teams Product package A, product package B etc all depends on package 1 and 2)

I am getting an error while deploying my metadata to fresh scratch org
`You reached the maximum number of allowed active filtered lookups (10) on Product.`
(Yes we asked Salesforce Support to increase the limit to 15)
So we decided to use `Org Shape` (though it's currently in Beta) and I was able to push my objects to Scratch orgs.

But while creating the package version it was throwing me the same error
`You reached the maximum number of allowed active filtered lookups (5) on Product.`
Apparently, Sfdx does not consider `Org Shape` while creating Unlock packages.
We used the `Org Dependent`(it's in beta) package for the Object-Base package to overcome this situation.

This worked as expected because Org dependent packages validate your metadata at run time.
While creating `Core package` with Object-Base package dependency it still throwing me the same error.
`You reached the maximum number of allowed active filtered lookups (5) on Product.`

One approach I am thinking of is to make the Lookup filter false while creating packages and update the metadata through `PostInstall` script (just like we use for Managed package) or mdapi commands to update the fields Lookup filter from `false` to `true`?
Or Is there any other workaround for my situation?
Unfortunately, PostInstall script doesn't work for Unlock packages and running Apex code through `Anonymous Window` to update Metadata also doesn't work as it throws `Cannot modify managed object: entity=NamedFilter, component=null, state=SECOND_GEN_INSTALLED_EDITABLE - filters (CANNOT_MODIFY_MANAGED_OBJECT)`

I don't want to use all my packages to be `OrgDependent` package as it's still in development and not sure if it will see any Daylight.

Comment: I don't see an option to add additional lookup filters, so Org Dependent is your only solution, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could make the lookup filters which exceed the limit as optional and then introduce a manual action after deploying the package in which the Lookup filters will be checked as required. That's the easiest workaround I can think of as we still don't have any possibility to adjust scratch orgs in regards of lookup filter limits.

Comment: Thanks, 
I tried that as well but we cannot update the Metadata via Metadata API for Unlock packages. The only solution seems to use the Org-Dependent package.

Comment: What I mean with manual action is doing it as a post deployment manual action via the UI by going to the field and checking the required checkbox

Comment: Ok. 
Actually, I cannot use it as we have a weekly release and every time package sees any changes it changes back to what the package has. 
plus we have total of 6 different orgs and it is simply impossible to change it manually for all 6 every week. 
But glad you found some workaround.